# My timer is 5 seconds faster per minute! cant find the mistake

Tags: nstimer

i got displayed min seconds and 1/100 seconds in this format 1:12.4

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/10 target:self selector:@selector(zeitMessung) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


-(void)zeitMessung{
    zeitMiSec +=1;
    if (zeitMiSec==9) {
        zeitSec+=1;
        zeitMiSec=0;
    }
    if (zeitSec==59) {
        zeitMin +=1;
        zeitSec =0;
    }

    if (zeitSec<10) {            
        NSString *nssTime = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%i:0%i.%i",zeitMin,zeitSec,zeitMiSec];
        lblTime.text= nssTime;
    }else{

        NSString *nssTime = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i.%i",zeitMin,zeitSec,zeitMiSec];
        lblTime.text= nssTime;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statments are a little out, so you turn over at .9 seconds and 59 seconds.

You need

```
if (zeitMiSec==10){...}
```

and

```
if (zeitSec==60){...}
```

Comment: @Andre: on the upside your bad day would be shorter by at least 24 minutes

Comment: @Andre No probs. Feel free to upvote & accept if its useful ;)